# Makefile: ...is up to date

Tags: c, makefile

I have made a makefile for some c files. I have seen too many ways on the internet but i had always the same problem: make: `q_a' is up to date.

```
q_a: 
gcc -o q_a quick_sort_i.c

q_g: 
gcc -o q_g quick_sort_g.c

s_a: 
gcc -o s_a shell_sort_i.c

s_g: 
gcc -o s_g shell_sort_g.c

fork: 
gcc -o fork fork.c
```

I have not files with the same name in my folder and I can compile them when I write in terminal. Can you help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: FYI: have you tried [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake_tutorial.html)? This tool could greatly simplify your "Makefiles".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have not specified dependencies for your targets.

What make does, is first checking if your target (`q_a`) exists as a file, and if it does, if its dependencies are newer (as in, have more recent modification time) as your target. Only if it needs to be updated (it does not exist or dependencies are newer) the rule is executed.

That means, if you need `q_a` to be recompiled every time `quick_sort_i.c` is changed, you need to add it as a dependency to `q_a`, like this:

```
q_a: quick_sort_i.c
    gcc -o q_a quick_sort_i.c
```

With that, make will recompile `q_a` if necessary.

Comment: I still have the same problem. I tried even this:
q_a:  quick_sort_i.o    ||   
 gcc -o q_a quick_sort_i.o   ||   

quick_sort_i.o: quick_sort_i.c   ||   
 gcc -o quick_sort_i.c -c    ||   

and i have the same problem too. Any other suggestion?

Comment: @a_user: it seems that you have a file q_a in the directory you are buildng in. If not, double check that the rules in your makefile are indented with tabs, if none of these help, try `touch quick_sort_i.c` and run make again. at least one of these should work.

Comment: @a_user: yes, if you only run `make` it will by default run the first rule of your makefile. if you need all targets to be built, add a target at the top like `all: q_a q_g s_a s_g fork`

Comment: @a_user yes, see my comment above :)